# Getting error when using hooks in functional component in react js which will be bundled into library and use in other app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rollup

I have created one functional component and used hooks and created library using rollup. when I uses that component in other application it is throwing below error:

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Note:

1. I have used const while declaring component.
2. If I take the code from library and put it into the application, it is working fine.

Comment: could you add a part of your code, or something that reproduces the error?

Comment: Run `npm ls react` at the terminal, and check in which part of the dependecies there is usage of mismatch version of react,  update package.json  anp `npm i` again

Comment: I agree with Adam, this question is missing the `code` section, please add it so we can take a look at it